# how to get monitor/display device names using WinAPI/C#

Tags: c#, winapi

I am working an application in C#/WPF and wanted to get the list of all attached display monitors. I used the Screen class and successfully got the list but now the list is having each monitor name as ".\Display1\XXXXXXXX" etc . which is not readable. However, My Nividia control panel list them as proper names. So can any one tell me how to get those names or some api reference.

Note := I already tried EnumDisplayDevices which is returning the names but they are different what it should be ? so its confusing the matters more ?

I tried WMI and it allowed me to access more information, however, the names are still "Default Monitor 1" "Default Monitor 2" while there is no information about manufacturer and now i am thinking does it available to us at all by using normal api's

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the actual Monitor name? as seen in the resolution dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958683/how-do-i-get-the-actual-monitor-name-as-seen-in-the-resolution-dialog)

Answer (score 7):

Query for Win32_DesktopMonitor in WMI.
[Msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394122(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Check out WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation).  It's not an easy library but it can tell you a ton of stuff about your system.