# How do I get the actual Monitor name? as seen in the resolution dialog

Tags: c#, windows, multiple-monitors

I am trying to grab the friendly name for the monitors on my system. I am using C#.

I have tried `Screen`, which just gives me `//./DisplayXX`. I have also tried both `Win32_DesktopMonitor` and `EnumDisplayDevices`, they all give me variations of `//./DisplayXX` OR `Generic Monitor`, whereas I know my displays names are `SyncMaster` and `SM2333T`.

Now Windows knows what these monitors are, displays them in the **Devices and Printers** windows with the correct names, and also in the dialog for setting location and resolution.

Where can I grab these names from? I have looked in the registry and cant seem to find them, so any help will be great.

**SOLUTION:**
The issue I had was when calling `EnumDisplayDevices` the second time I was setting `iDevNum` to id again, which meant I was trying to grab data from the wrong place, I then replaced this with 0, and it works perfectly, see below for the code.

```
    var device = new DISPLAY_DEVICE();
    device.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(device);
    try
    {
        for (uint id = 0; EnumDisplayDevices(null, id, ref device, 0); id++)
        { 
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}", id, device.DeviceName, device.DeviceString, device.StateFlags, device.DeviceID, device.DeviceKey));
                Console.WriteLine();
                device.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(device);

                EnumDisplayDevices(device.DeviceName, 0, ref device, 0);

                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}", id, device.DeviceName, device.DeviceString, device.StateFlags, device.DeviceID, device.DeviceKey));
                device.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(device);

                device.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(device);
                return;
            }

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", ex.ToString()));
    }
```

Comment: It seems like you can't http://stackoverflow.com/a/24375561/67824

Comment: @OhadSchneider take a look at my question, I have provided a solution and this has been working fine in that project for a long time now.

Comment: The answer is right here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26404982/how-get-monitors-friendly-name-with-winapi

Comment: https://github.com/r1me/delphi-monitorhelper

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After you get a `DisplayDevice.DeviceName` like `//./DisplayX` from `EnumDisplayDevices`, you are supposed to call 'EnumDisplayDevices' a second time, this time providing the 'DisplayDevice.DeviceName' that you got from the previous call as `lpDevice`, and '0' as `iDevNum`. Then you'll have the monitor name in `DisplayDevice.DeviceString`.

Comment: Ah! I will check that out, I did do the second called but was looking under DeviceName again ;) Thanks, If this would I will mark as correct

Comment: Nope that didnt work it either gave me an empty string or Generic PNP Monitor not its actual name :(

Comment: @James - There's something strange with that result, you shouldn't get either this or that. You should always get the same string with every call. BTW, I never saw a monitor entry in the 'devices and printers' view, that's new for me. Are those names the same with what you see in 'Device Manager' under 'Monitors'?

Comment: When I said either empty or generic I meant for each monitor, as I have 5 on this machine. In Device Manager they all show as Generic Pnp Monitors except for the SyncMaster.

Comment: Oh an as for the monitors in Devices and Printers I think its a windows7 thing as Ive never seen it before either :)

Comment: @James - I see, thanks. Perhaps you just have too much monitors for EnumDisplayDevices to handle. ;) You might like to give it a shot with WMI, here's an [example](http://myitforum.com/cs2/blogs/rzander/archive/2009/03/30/wmi-provider-to-list-the-monitors-serialnr-and-model-name.aspx).

Comment: @Sertac I tried WMI and it only gives me 3 displays :S I finally got it to return the right values, we were both almost there. I will post my solution, now.

Comment: This post helped me to find the solution, which I have posted in the original question.

Comment: @James - I had mentioned 'iDevNum' would be passed '0' for the second call in the answer. ;) Glad you sorted it out in any case. :)

Comment: oops! so you did :S sorry about that.

Comment: Interesting; this doesn't work for me.  It only gives me "Generic PnP Monitor", whereas the Control Panel shows "SyncMaster".

Comment: I get the same results as @luke. It returns "Generic PnP Monitor" for all monitors.

Answer (score 26):

Examine carefully! this is what you looking for,
you can now write `Screen.PrimaryScreen.DeviceFriendlyName()` and get the real name of the monitor device. 
**(and yes, it is the same name seen in resolution dialog)**

While I did add some personal touch to wrap this code I did not create the Hard-Core part of it,
And so I would like to thank 2 developers, The MS developer who gave the essentials in C++ and the anonymous developer who translated those essentials to C# code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Tools;

namespace ConsoleApplication35
{
    internal class Program
    {

        private static void Main()
        {

            Console.WriteLine(Screen.PrimaryScreen.DeviceFriendlyName());

            //output: ASUS MK241

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

namespace Tools
{
    public static class ScreenInterrogatory
    {
        public const int ERROR_SUCCESS = 0;

        #region enums

        public enum QUERY_DEVICE_CONFIG_FLAGS : uint
        {
            QDC_ALL_PATHS = 0x00000001,
            QDC_ONLY_ACTIVE_PATHS = 0x00000002,
            QDC_DATABASE_CURRENT = 0x00000004
        }

        public enum DISPLAYCONFIG_VIDEO_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY : uint
        {
            DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_OTHER = 0xFFFFFFFF,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_HD15 = 0,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_SVIDEO = 1,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_COMPOSITE_VIDEO = 2,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_COMPONENT_VIDEO = 3,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_DVI = 4,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_HDMI = 5,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_LVDS = 6,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_D_JPN = 8,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_SDI = 9,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_DISPLAYPORT_EXTERNAL = 10,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_DISPLAYPORT_EMBEDDED = 11,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_UDI_EXTERNAL = 12,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_UDI_EMBEDDED = 13,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_SDTVDONGLE = 14,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_MIRACAST = 15,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_INTERNAL = 0x80000000,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_FORCE_UINT32 = 0xFFFFFFFF
        }

        public enum DISPLAYCONFIG_SCANLINE_ORDERING : uint
        {
            DISPLAYCONFIG_SCANLINE_ORDERING_UNSPECIFIED = 0,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_SCANLINE_ORDERING_PROGRESSIVE = 1,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_SCANLINE_ORDERING_INTERLACED = 2,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_SCANLINE_ORDERING_INTERLACED_UPPERFIELDFIRST = DISPLAYCONFIG_SCANLINE_ORDERING_INTERLACED,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_SCANLINE_ORDERING_INTERLACED_LOWERFIELDFIRST = 3,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_SCANLINE_ORDERING_FORCE_UINT32 = 0xFFFFFFFF
        }

        public enum DISPLAYCONFIG_ROTATION : uint
        {
            DISPLAYCONFIG_ROTATION_IDENTITY = 1,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_ROTATION_ROTATE90 = 2,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_ROTATION_ROTATE180 = 3,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_ROTATION_ROTATE270 = 4,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_ROTATION_FORCE_UINT32 = 0xFFFFFFFF
        }

        public enum DISPLAYCONFIG_SCALING : uint
        {
            DISPLAYCONFIG_SCALING_IDENTITY = 1,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_SCALING_CENTERED = 2,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_SCALING_STRETCHED = 3,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_SCALING_ASPECTRATIOCENTEREDMAX = 4,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_SCALING_CUSTOM = 5,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_SCALING_PREFERRED = 128,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_SCALING_FORCE_UINT32 = 0xFFFFFFFF
        }

        public enum DISPLAYCONFIG_PIXELFORMAT : uint
        {
            DISPLAYCONFIG_PIXELFORMAT_8BPP = 1,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_PIXELFORMAT_16BPP = 2,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_PIXELFORMAT_24BPP = 3,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_PIXELFORMAT_32BPP = 4,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_PIXELFORMAT_NONGDI = 5,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_PIXELFORMAT_FORCE_UINT32 = 0xffffffff
        }

        public enum DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO_TYPE : uint
        {
            DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO_TYPE_SOURCE = 1,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO_TYPE_TARGET = 2,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO_TYPE_FORCE_UINT32 = 0xFFFFFFFF
        }

        public enum DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_TYPE : uint
        {
            DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_GET_SOURCE_NAME = 1,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_GET_TARGET_NAME = 2,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_GET_TARGET_PREFERRED_MODE = 3,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_GET_ADAPTER_NAME = 4,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_SET_TARGET_PERSISTENCE = 5,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_GET_TARGET_BASE_TYPE = 6,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_FORCE_UINT32 = 0xFFFFFFFF
        }

        #endregion

        #region structs

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct LUID
        {
            public uint LowPart;
            public int HighPart;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_SOURCE_INFO
        {
            public LUID adapterId;
            public uint id;
            public uint modeInfoIdx;
            public uint statusFlags;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_TARGET_INFO
        {
            public LUID adapterId;
            public uint id;
            public uint modeInfoIdx;
            private DISPLAYCONFIG_VIDEO_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY outputTechnology;
            private DISPLAYCONFIG_ROTATION rotation;
            private DISPLAYCONFIG_SCALING scaling;
            private DISPLAYCONFIG_RATIONAL refreshRate;
            private DISPLAYCONFIG_SCANLINE_ORDERING scanLineOrdering;
            public bool targetAvailable;
            public uint statusFlags;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct DISPLAYCONFIG_RATIONAL
        {
            public uint Numerator;
            public uint Denominator;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO
        {
            public DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_SOURCE_INFO sourceInfo;
            public DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_TARGET_INFO targetInfo;
            public uint flags;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct DISPLAYCONFIG_2DREGION
        {
            public uint cx;
            public uint cy;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct DISPLAYCONFIG_VIDEO_SIGNAL_INFO
        {
            public ulong pixelRate;
            public DISPLAYCONFIG_RATIONAL hSyncFreq;
            public DISPLAYCONFIG_RATIONAL vSyncFreq;
            public DISPLAYCONFIG_2DREGION activeSize;
            public DISPLAYCONFIG_2DREGION totalSize;
            public uint videoStandard;
            public DISPLAYCONFIG_SCANLINE_ORDERING scanLineOrdering;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct DISPLAYCONFIG_TARGET_MODE
        {
            public DISPLAYCONFIG_VIDEO_SIGNAL_INFO targetVideoSignalInfo;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct POINTL
        {
            private int x;
            private int y;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct DISPLAYCONFIG_SOURCE_MODE
        {
            public uint width;
            public uint height;
            public DISPLAYCONFIG_PIXELFORMAT pixelFormat;
            public POINTL position;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
        public struct DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO_UNION
        {
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public DISPLAYCONFIG_TARGET_MODE targetMode;

            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public DISPLAYCONFIG_SOURCE_MODE sourceMode;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO
        {
            public DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO_TYPE infoType;
            public uint id;
            public LUID adapterId;
            public DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO_UNION modeInfo;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct DISPLAYCONFIG_TARGET_DEVICE_NAME_FLAGS
        {
            public uint value;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_HEADER
        {
            public DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_TYPE type;
            public uint size;
            public LUID adapterId;
            public uint id;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public struct DISPLAYCONFIG_TARGET_DEVICE_NAME
        {
            public DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_HEADER header;
            public DISPLAYCONFIG_TARGET_DEVICE_NAME_FLAGS flags;
            public DISPLAYCONFIG_VIDEO_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY outputTechnology;
            public ushort edidManufactureId;
            public ushort edidProductCodeId;
            public uint connectorInstance;

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 64)]
            public string monitorFriendlyDeviceName;

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
            public string monitorDevicePath;
        }

        #endregion

        #region DLL-Imports

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int GetDisplayConfigBufferSizes(
            QUERY_DEVICE_CONFIG_FLAGS flags, out uint numPathArrayElements, out uint numModeInfoArrayElements);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int QueryDisplayConfig(
            QUERY_DEVICE_CONFIG_FLAGS flags,
            ref uint numPathArrayElements, [Out] DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO[] PathInfoArray,
            ref uint numModeInfoArrayElements, [Out] DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO[] ModeInfoArray,
            IntPtr currentTopologyId
            );

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int DisplayConfigGetDeviceInfo(ref DISPLAYCONFIG_TARGET_DEVICE_NAME deviceName);

        #endregion

        private static string MonitorFriendlyName(LUID adapterId, uint targetId)
        {
            var deviceName = new DISPLAYCONFIG_TARGET_DEVICE_NAME
            {
                header =
                {
                    size = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof (DISPLAYCONFIG_TARGET_DEVICE_NAME)),
                    adapterId = adapterId,
                    id = targetId,
                    type = DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_TYPE.DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_GET_TARGET_NAME
                }
            };
            var error = DisplayConfigGetDeviceInfo(ref deviceName);
            if (error != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                throw new Win32Exception(error);
            return deviceName.monitorFriendlyDeviceName;
        }

        private static IEnumerable<string> GetAllMonitorsFriendlyNames()
        {
            uint pathCount, modeCount;
            var error = GetDisplayConfigBufferSizes(QUERY_DEVICE_CONFIG_FLAGS.QDC_ONLY_ACTIVE_PATHS, out pathCount, out modeCount);
            if (error != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                throw new Win32Exception(error);

            var displayPaths = new DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO[pathCount];
            var displayModes = new DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO[modeCount];
            error = QueryDisplayConfig(QUERY_DEVICE_CONFIG_FLAGS.QDC_ONLY_ACTIVE_PATHS,
                ref pathCount, displayPaths, ref modeCount, displayModes, IntPtr.Zero);
            if (error != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                throw new Win32Exception(error);

            for (var i = 0; i < modeCount; i++)
                if (displayModes[i].infoType == DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO_TYPE.DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO_TYPE_TARGET)
                    yield return MonitorFriendlyName(displayModes[i].adapterId, displayModes[i].id);
        }

        public static string DeviceFriendlyName(this Screen screen)
        {
            var allFriendlyNames = GetAllMonitorsFriendlyNames();
            for (var index = 0; index < Screen.AllScreens.Length; index++)
                if (Equals(screen, Screen.AllScreens[index]))
                    return allFriendlyNames.ToArray()[index];
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, that just what I wanted :)

Comment: Great answer that successfully works. 
The only missing answer is the ability to query for Front Porch, Sync, and Back Porch.  I would like to figure out a way to query for full video signal timings information.

Comment: Can your solution be extended and get a diagonal size? Or physical width and height?

Comment: @Puty you mean "physical" - as how many inches? nah - I don't think it exists anywhere electronically, I think only pixels count is available. but you could have a long dictionary of all models and etc.. but then.. who will maintain it? I suggest you just let your user define it per screen if you need that information available for some processing.

Comment: @G.Y, I don't really need to know the physical size of the screen (in inches), but I need to find out the PPI (pixel per inch). I only need the physical size to calculate the PPI. Is there any way to find out the PPI of all connected monitors? Now I use "WmiMonitorBasicDisplayParams" class but the properties "MaxHorizontalImageSize" and "MaxVerticalImageSize" are only uint8 and do not match exactly with the device physical width and height.

Comment: For those that want a C/C++ version of this, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-querydisplayconfig#examples is an example in the MS docs

Answer (score 5):

This information is almost certainly obtained through the [SetupAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff550897.aspx) family of functions.  I don't recall the specifics off the top of my head, but you will need to get all monitor devices (GUID_DEVINTERFACE_MONITOR) and obtain their friendly names (SPDRP_FRIENDLYNAME).

Comment: I tried to do as you suggest to no avail, would be great if you could take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24356289/setupdigetdeviceregistryproperty-fails-with-error-invalid-data

Answer (score 4):

From here: [Get Exact Monitor/Display/Screen Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14989079/get-exact-monitor-display-screen-name)

Well, this question is old, however, as for the sake of google redirects, I suggest my 'WindowsDisplayAPI' library.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsDisplayAPI

---

Using the library, there are multiple ways to get the display name. The simplest way is:

```
foreach (var display in Display.GetDisplays())
{
    Console.WriteLine(display.DeviceName);
}
```

But this is using the old API, if you are sure that your program targets at least Windows Vista, I suggest the following code:

```
foreach (var target in DisplayConfig.PathDisplayTarget.GetDisplayTargets())
{
    Console.WriteLine(target.FriendlyName);
}
```

Comment: You should probably mention you are the author.

Comment: @RonnieW, done. Not that it mattered tho, both the GitHub project page and the NuGet package page clearly state that.

Comment: Beware, the NuGet is under LGPL v3.

Comment: @YurySchkatula, you are confusing LGPL with GPL.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13532034/1913051

Answer (score 0):

I have been seraching for an answer to this same question. In [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23407024/enumdisplaydevices-return-value-is-generic-pnp-monitor-c-sharp) it is mentioned that generic pnp monitor is shown, because there is no driver installed for the monitor and the device  is running with the Generic PnP Monitor Driver.

For windows 7 and higher there seems to be a different function than EnumDisplayDevices to get the desired display names as shown in the control panel. This can be done with the DisplayConfigGetDeviceInfo function as explained [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cede9420-bc64-45e9-867c-f15920fb2c98/c-enumerate-monitor-name-get-same-name-used-in-control-panel-screen-resolution?forum=csharpgeneral). I hope someone soon can translate this to Delphi, which I am looking for.