# Get Exact Monitor/Display/Screen Name

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application

I have a program where user chooses destination monitor but I just can't get the real monitor
name/model.

I have already tried the following:

- Screen.AllScreens is of no use;
- WMI and Win32 EnumDisplayDevices both returns Generic PnP Monitor;
- Device Manager also shows Generic PnP Monitor...

In explorer there are the actual names of monitors attached and in Everest, it shows even more depth in details...

From where these 2 programs gets those information? The last option I ran into
is to parse EDID from registry ... has anyone tried this and did it work?

Comment: Before you get carried away with this, how are you going to handle the *very* common case where the two monitors are exactly the same make and model?

Comment: I'm not worried about that ... I could, I suppose, based on screen bounds determinate the location of screen eg. left, right etc. If there are only two I could just append primary to the main one. But before I get this far, I must first get those information.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the actual Monitor name? as seen in the resolution dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958683/how-do-i-get-the-actual-monitor-name-as-seen-in-the-resolution-dialog)

Answer (score 9):

Well, this question is old, however, as for the sake of google redirects, I suggest the 'WindowsDisplayAPI' library.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsDisplayAPI

---

Using the library, there are multiple ways to get the display name. The simplest way is:

```
foreach (var display in Display.GetDisplays())
{
    Console.WriteLine(display.DeviceName);
}
```

But this is using the old API, if you are sure that your program targets at least Windows Vista, I suggest the following code:

```
foreach (var target in DisplayConfig.PathDisplayTarget.GetDisplayTargets())
{
    Console.WriteLine(target.FriendlyName);
}
```

Comment: Yep - after an evening of searching - this brings all the different methods together. Only 64kb to boot. Thanks @Soroush

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this might have already been answered in a different question:
[How do i get the actual monitor name as seen in the resolution dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958683/how-do-i-get-the-actual-monitor-name-as-seen-in-the-resolution-dialog)

Comment: I have already read that post, but couldn't find any function in setup api library which would provide me the data I need.