# SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty fails with ERROR_INVALID_DATA

Tags: c#, winapi, interop

I'm trying to get the display names as they appear in the "Screen Resolution" window (Win8.1 x64).

First I tried `EnumDisplayDevices`

```
var deviceInfo = new DISPLAY_DEVICEW();
uint i = 0;
while (true)
{
    if (!NativeMethods.EnumDisplayDevices(null, i++, deviceInfo, 0))
    {
        break;
    }
    PrintDeviceInfo(deviceInfo);

    NativeMethods.EnumDisplayDevices(deviceInfo.DeviceName, 0, deviceInfo, EDD_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_NAME);
    PrintDeviceInfo(deviceInfo);
}
```

The second call to `EnumDisplayDevices` (with `EDD_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_NAME`) indeed yielded the display name as it appears for my main display (in DISPLAY_DEVICEW.DeviceString). However for my HDMI-connected TV that field contains *Generic PnP Monitor*, instead of *SAMSUNG* as it appears in the "Screen Resolution" Window. Perhaps the fact that it's connected by HDMI is somehow related?

I then tried the Setup API

```
var hdevinfo = NativeMethods.SetupDiGetClassDevs(ref GUID_DEVINTERFACE_MONITOR, null, IntPtr.Zero, DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE | DIGCF_PRESENT);
if (hdevinfo == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return;
var spDeviceInterfaceData = new SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA();
uint memberIndex = 0;
while (true)
{
    bool success = NativeMethods.SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(hdevinfo, null, ref GUID_DEVINTERFACE_MONITOR, memberIndex++, spDeviceInterfaceData);
    if (!success)
    {
        break;
    }
    PrintInterfaceData(spDeviceInterfaceData);

    uint requiredSize;
    var devInfoData = new SP_DEVINFO_DATA();

    NativeMethods.SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hdevinfo, spDeviceInterfaceData, IntPtr.Zero, 0, out requiredSize, devInfoData);
    PrintDevInfoData(devInfoData);

    var interfaceDetail = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)requiredSize);
    var cbSize = (Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(uint)) + Marshal.SystemDefaultCharSize);
    Marshal.WriteInt32(interfaceDetail, 0, cbSize);
    NativeMethods.SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hdevinfo, spDeviceInterfaceData, interfaceDetail, requiredSize, IntPtr.Zero, null);
    var dynamicType = GetDeviceInterfaceDetailDataType(requiredSize);
    var interfaceDetailStruct = Marshal.PtrToStructure(interfaceDetail, dynamicType);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(interfaceDetail);
    PrintInterfaceDetail(interfaceDetailStruct);

    uint propertyRegDataType;
    NativeMethods.SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(hdevinfo, devInfoData, SPDRP_FRIENDLYNAME, out propertyRegDataType, null, 0, out requiredSize);
    Console.WriteLine(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
}
```

Looking at the returned values from the different methods, everything seems to work, but the last call to `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty` fails with `ERROR_INVALID_DATA` (that is, the method returns false and `GetLastWin32Error` yields `13`). According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551967%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), this means that *the requested property does not exist for a device or if the property data is not valid*.

I actually looped over all possible `SPDRP` values (0-24) and they all result in the same failure. Just to clarify, I expected the method to fail, but with `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER` and having `requiredSize` set (the latter simply retains its previous value, as the unmanaged code doesn't change it).

Here's the signature for `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty` (all other methods work as expected):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class SP_DEVINFO_DATA
{
    public uint cbSize = (uint) Marshal.SizeOf(typeof (SP_DEVINFO_DATA));
    public Guid ClassGuid;
    public uint DevInst;
    public IntPtr Reserved;
}
[DllImport("setupapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(
    IntPtr deviceInfoSet,
    SP_DEVINFO_DATA deviceInfoData, 
    uint property, 
    out uint propertyRegDataType, 
    byte[] propertyBuffer, 
    uint propertyBufferSize, 
    out uint requiredSize);
```

Comment: Why are you ignoring all the return values?  Have you tried doing this with C++ first, where the Windows API provides header files with the correct definitions and you don't need to write your own?

Comment: There can also be more than one device interface on a device node.

Comment: I iterate over all devices. I'm not ignoring the return values, simply omitted them for brevity. In my actual test program I print all return values, Win32 errors, and values / structs returned.

Comment: I don't see where you're actually using the result from `EnumDisplayDevices`

Comment: oh I think I understand, you mean the memberIndex parameter. Good catch, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: I don't, I just print it. Where would I use it ?

Comment: "Set this flag to EDD_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_NAME (0x00000001) to retrieve the device interface name for GUID_DEVINTERFACE_MONITOR, which is registered by the operating system on a per monitor basis. The value is placed in the DeviceID member of the DISPLAY_DEVICE structure returned in lpDisplayDevice. The resulting device interface name can be used with SetupAPI functions and serves as a link between GDI monitor devices and SetupAPI monitor devices."  But you never use the `DeviceID`

Comment: You're also not disposing the various data structures properly, maybe your real code does.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56075/discussion-between-ben-voigt-and-ohad-schneider).

Comment: "I omitted then for brevity". In other words, this is not the code that you are running. I for one don't want to get into debugging fake code.

Comment: @BenVoigt you're right, putting the SetupAPI calls in the loop was idiotic (I should probably stop coding at 1AM next time, which is incidentally the reason I didn't get into the chat as you (generously!) offered). The question is formulated more clearly now. Regarding using the DeviceID - where ? The only SetupAPI candidate I can see is `SetupDiGetClassDevs`, specifically its `Enumerator` parameter (assuming DeviceID is a *device instance ID*). Anyway, that doesn't work (I get back `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`). I also *think* it won't help, as IM enumerating **all** interfaces in the SetupAPI now.

Comment: @BenVoigt Regarding disposing the data structures you're right, but right now I'm not overly concerned with that (and even when the tool I'm writing is done it may not matter much as these methods will only  be called once).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan This code is the exact code I'm working on, except a few `Console.Writeline`s I omitted to keep things focused on the essence of the problem. I could post the entire code on some pastebin if you prefer of course, but I really think that won't get us any closer to whatever it is I'm missing...

Comment: @OhadSchneider: Click the chat link above; I added more information there.

Comment: OK. That's your call.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I posted the entire code for reference here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7692130/ - once I get it to work it's going to be committed to my open source project anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like what I'm looking for is [impossible](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/668e3cf9-4e00-4b40-a6f8-c7d2fc1afd39/how-can-i-retrieve-monitor-information?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues):

> There is not a supported way to figour out the IDs that you referred
>   to programmatically. It was never a design goal to provide a way for
>   applications to label monitors with the same IDs that the screen
>   resolution control panel uses