# How do I get the actual monitor name in JAVA? As seen in the resolution dialog

Tags: java, windows, java-native-interface, multiple-monitors, device-name

Is there any possibility to get the "FriendlyDeviceName" of all screen devices, currently connected to my Windows PC (Win7), in Java?

I think about the actual monitor name as seen in the resolution dialogue. For example "SyncMaster".

There's already a solution done in C#:

[How do I get the actual Monitor name? as seen in the resolution dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958683/how-do-i-get-the-actual-monitor-name-as-seen-in-the-resolution-dialog)

Is it possible to do this in "normal" Java or do I need some JNI stuff?

Comment: You mean something like [`GraphicsDevice#getIDstring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html#getIDstring()) or the actual "monitor" hardware name?

Comment: I mean the actual hardware name, as seen in the windows resolution dialogue. That device descriptions are different from IDstring.

Comment: You'll need to hit a JNA/JNI solution for that then

Comment: Any idea how to do that?