# Getting device friendly name - incorrect result

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm getting a device friendly name using code written by [@G.A (link)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28257839/9220993). Everything works good until I lock my windows account for couple of minutes. After unlock, calling function DeviceFriendlyName(screen) giving me wrong screen name - first screen got name of second, and second screen got name of first. Do anyone know how to fix it programatically? I've found, that reconnecting screen fixes it. Can I refresh screen informations using c# code?

Code used to get device friendly name:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Tools;

namespace ConsoleApplication35
{
    internal class Program
    {

        private static void Main()
        {

            foreach(var screen in Screen.AllScreens)
                Console.WriteLine(screen.DeviceFriendlyName());

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

namespace Tools
{
    public static class ScreenInterrogatory
    {
        public const int ERROR_SUCCESS = 0;

        #region enums

        public enum QUERY_DEVICE_CONFIG_FLAGS : uint
        {
            QDC_ALL_PATHS = 0x00000001,
            QDC_ONLY_ACTIVE_PATHS = 0x00000002,
            QDC_DATABASE_CURRENT = 0x00000004
        }

        public enum DISPLAYCONFIG_VIDEO_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY : uint
        {
            DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_OTHER = 0xFFFFFFFF,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_HD15 = 0,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_SVIDEO = 1,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_COMPOSITE_VIDEO = 2,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_COMPONENT_VIDEO = 3,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_DVI = 4,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_HDMI = 5,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_LVDS = 6,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_D_JPN = 8,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_SDI = 9,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_DISPLAYPORT_EXTERNAL = 10,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_DISPLAYPORT_EMBEDDED = 11,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_UDI_EXTERNAL = 12,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_UDI_EMBEDDED = 13,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_SDTVDONGLE = 14,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_MIRACAST = 15,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_INTERNAL = 0x80000000,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_FORCE_UINT32 = 0xFFFFFFFF
        }

        public enum DISPLAYCONFIG_SCANLINE_ORDERING : uint
        {
            DISPLAYCONFIG_SCANLINE_ORDERING_UNSPECIFIED = 0,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_SCANLINE_ORDERING_PROGRESSIVE = 1,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_SCANLINE_ORDERING_INTERLACED = 2,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_SCANLINE_ORDERING_INTERLACED_UPPERFIELDFIRST = DISPLAYCONFIG_SCANLINE_ORDERING_INTERLACED,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_SCANLINE_ORDERING_INTERLACED_LOWERFIELDFIRST = 3,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_SCANLINE_ORDERING_FORCE_UINT32 = 0xFFFFFFFF
        }

        public enum DISPLAYCONFIG_ROTATION : uint
        {
            DISPLAYCONFIG_ROTATION_IDENTITY = 1,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_ROTATION_ROTATE90 = 2,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_ROTATION_ROTATE180 = 3,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_ROTATION_ROTATE270 = 4,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_ROTATION_FORCE_UINT32 = 0xFFFFFFFF
        }

        public enum DISPLAYCONFIG_SCALING : uint
        {
            DISPLAYCONFIG_SCALING_IDENTITY = 1,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_SCALING_CENTERED = 2,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_SCALING_STRETCHED = 3,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_SCALING_ASPECTRATIOCENTEREDMAX = 4,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_SCALING_CUSTOM = 5,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_SCALING_PREFERRED = 128,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_SCALING_FORCE_UINT32 = 0xFFFFFFFF
        }

        public enum DISPLAYCONFIG_PIXELFORMAT : uint
        {
            DISPLAYCONFIG_PIXELFORMAT_8BPP = 1,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_PIXELFORMAT_16BPP = 2,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_PIXELFORMAT_24BPP = 3,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_PIXELFORMAT_32BPP = 4,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_PIXELFORMAT_NONGDI = 5,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_PIXELFORMAT_FORCE_UINT32 = 0xffffffff
        }

        public enum DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO_TYPE : uint
        {
            DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO_TYPE_SOURCE = 1,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO_TYPE_TARGET = 2,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO_TYPE_FORCE_UINT32 = 0xFFFFFFFF
        }

        public enum DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_TYPE : uint
        {
            DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_GET_SOURCE_NAME = 1,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_GET_TARGET_NAME = 2,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_GET_TARGET_PREFERRED_MODE = 3,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_GET_ADAPTER_NAME = 4,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_SET_TARGET_PERSISTENCE = 5,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_GET_TARGET_BASE_TYPE = 6,
            DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_FORCE_UINT32 = 0xFFFFFFFF
        }

        #endregion

        #region structs

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct LUID
        {
            public uint LowPart;
            public int HighPart;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_SOURCE_INFO
        {
            public LUID adapterId;
            public uint id;
            public uint modeInfoIdx;
            public uint statusFlags;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_TARGET_INFO
        {
            public LUID adapterId;
            public uint id;
            public uint modeInfoIdx;
            private DISPLAYCONFIG_VIDEO_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY outputTechnology;
            private DISPLAYCONFIG_ROTATION rotation;
            private DISPLAYCONFIG_SCALING scaling;
            private DISPLAYCONFIG_RATIONAL refreshRate;
            private DISPLAYCONFIG_SCANLINE_ORDERING scanLineOrdering;
            public bool targetAvailable;
            public uint statusFlags;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct DISPLAYCONFIG_RATIONAL
        {
            public uint Numerator;
            public uint Denominator;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO
        {
            public DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_SOURCE_INFO sourceInfo;
            public DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_TARGET_INFO targetInfo;
            public uint flags;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct DISPLAYCONFIG_2DREGION
        {
            public uint cx;
            public uint cy;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct DISPLAYCONFIG_VIDEO_SIGNAL_INFO
        {
            public ulong pixelRate;
            public DISPLAYCONFIG_RATIONAL hSyncFreq;
            public DISPLAYCONFIG_RATIONAL vSyncFreq;
            public DISPLAYCONFIG_2DREGION activeSize;
            public DISPLAYCONFIG_2DREGION totalSize;
            public uint videoStandard;
            public DISPLAYCONFIG_SCANLINE_ORDERING scanLineOrdering;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct DISPLAYCONFIG_TARGET_MODE
        {
            public DISPLAYCONFIG_VIDEO_SIGNAL_INFO targetVideoSignalInfo;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct POINTL
        {
            private int x;
            private int y;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct DISPLAYCONFIG_SOURCE_MODE
        {
            public uint width;
            public uint height;
            public DISPLAYCONFIG_PIXELFORMAT pixelFormat;
            public POINTL position;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
        public struct DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO_UNION
        {
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public DISPLAYCONFIG_TARGET_MODE targetMode;

            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public DISPLAYCONFIG_SOURCE_MODE sourceMode;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO
        {
            public DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO_TYPE infoType;
            public uint id;
            public LUID adapterId;
            public DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO_UNION modeInfo;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct DISPLAYCONFIG_TARGET_DEVICE_NAME_FLAGS
        {
            public uint value;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_HEADER
        {
            public DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_TYPE type;
            public uint size;
            public LUID adapterId;
            public uint id;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public struct DISPLAYCONFIG_TARGET_DEVICE_NAME
        {
            public DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_HEADER header;
            public DISPLAYCONFIG_TARGET_DEVICE_NAME_FLAGS flags;
            public DISPLAYCONFIG_VIDEO_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY outputTechnology;
            public ushort edidManufactureId;
            public ushort edidProductCodeId;
            public uint connectorInstance;

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 64)]
            public string monitorFriendlyDeviceName;

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
            public string monitorDevicePath;
        }

        #endregion

        #region DLL-Imports

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int GetDisplayConfigBufferSizes(
            QUERY_DEVICE_CONFIG_FLAGS flags, out uint numPathArrayElements, out uint numModeInfoArrayElements);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int QueryDisplayConfig(
            QUERY_DEVICE_CONFIG_FLAGS flags,
            ref uint numPathArrayElements, [Out] DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO[] PathInfoArray,
            ref uint numModeInfoArrayElements, [Out] DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO[] ModeInfoArray,
            IntPtr currentTopologyId
            );

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int DisplayConfigGetDeviceInfo(ref DISPLAYCONFIG_TARGET_DEVICE_NAME deviceName);

        #endregion

        private static string MonitorFriendlyName(LUID adapterId, uint targetId)
        {
            var deviceName = new DISPLAYCONFIG_TARGET_DEVICE_NAME
            {
                header =
                {
                    size = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof (DISPLAYCONFIG_TARGET_DEVICE_NAME)),
                    adapterId = adapterId,
                    id = targetId,
                    type = DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_TYPE.DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_GET_TARGET_NAME
                }
            };
            var error = DisplayConfigGetDeviceInfo(ref deviceName);
            if (error != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                throw new Win32Exception(error);
            return deviceName.monitorFriendlyDeviceName;
        }

        private static IEnumerable<string> GetAllMonitorsFriendlyNames()
        {
            uint pathCount, modeCount;
            var error = GetDisplayConfigBufferSizes(QUERY_DEVICE_CONFIG_FLAGS.QDC_ONLY_ACTIVE_PATHS, out pathCount, out modeCount);
            if (error != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                throw new Win32Exception(error);

            var displayPaths = new DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO[pathCount];
            var displayModes = new DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO[modeCount];
            error = QueryDisplayConfig(QUERY_DEVICE_CONFIG_FLAGS.QDC_ONLY_ACTIVE_PATHS,
                ref pathCount, displayPaths, ref modeCount, displayModes, IntPtr.Zero);
            if (error != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                throw new Win32Exception(error);

            for (var i = 0; i < modeCount; i++)
                if (displayModes[i].infoType == DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO_TYPE.DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO_TYPE_TARGET)
                    yield return MonitorFriendlyName(displayModes[i].adapterId, displayModes[i].id);
        }

        public static string DeviceFriendlyName(this Screen screen)
        {
            var allFriendlyNames = GetAllMonitorsFriendlyNames();
            for (var index = 0; index < Screen.AllScreens.Length; index++)
                if (Equals(screen, Screen.AllScreens[index]))
                    return allFriendlyNames.ToArray()[index];
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

Regards,
Hawex

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: question was edited, thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my case helped changing

```
QUERY_DEVICE_CONFIG_FLAGS.QDC_ONLY_ACTIVE_PATHS
```

to:

```
QUERY_DEVICE_CONFIG_FLAGS.QDC_ALL_PATHS
```

In GetAllMonitorsFriendlyNames()  (2 occurences)

based on:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-querydisplayconfig

> Note
>
> In the case of any temporary modes, the QDC_ONLY_ACTIVE_PATHS setting
> means the mode data returned may not be the same as that which is
> stored in the persistence database.

I would rather go for QUERY_DEVICE_CONFIG_FLAGS.QDC_DATABASE_CURRENT but this parameter throws an error. Above solution works in 4 monitor setup. Original code works for 2 monitors, but from 3 and above gives incorrect results.

Answer (score 0):

I've found, that calling process `%Windir%\System32\displayswitch.exe /internal` and after `%Windir%\System32\displayswitch.exe /extend` will "refresh" informations, which is given by function DeviceFriendlyName(screen), and after that everything seems to be ok.

However, if anyone have any other, better solution, please post it here.

Hawex

Comment: Using [WMI queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management), you have the `WmiMonitorID` class that returns the device `UserFriendlyName` property. It's in the `@"\root\WMI"` scope (not `CIMV2`). It can be combined with `Win32_DesktopMonitor` in the `@"\root\CIMV2"` scope for more informations.